# Como cambiar de actividad en la misma pantalla en android?

Tags: android

Saludos...alguien me podria explicar como puedo cambiar de actividad en una misma pantalla, es decir poder cambiar de layouts en una misma pantalla a traves de botones, tipo twitter. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 1):

lo que estás buscando son los `fragmentos`, twitter en ese layout que ves ahí está usando dichos fragmentos.

En el ejemplo de Twitter que mencionas básicamente el layout de la actividad consta de un toolbar arriba con los 4 iconos y un layout interno que albergará uno de los cuatro fragmentos, estos se irán alternando según en que icono pinchas.

De esta manera cuando pinchas en un icono se hace una "transacción" y se remplaza el fragmento actual que se encuentra en el layout interno por el que corresponde al icono pulsado, todo eso por supuesto sin cambiar de actividad.

Los fragmentos fueron introducidos para ayudar a producir UI que se pueda adaptar a diversas orientaciones de dispositivo así como funcionar perfectamente en teléfonos y tabletas. Incluso puedes utilizar diferentes fragmentos dentro de la misma actividad y reorganizarlos cuando el usuario gira su dispositivo.

Pincha en este [enlace](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=es-419) para informarte mejor de su utilización, después de haber leído un poco por encima de que trata, si haces scroll hacia abajo encontrarás un ejemplo sencillo y bien explicado de como crear e implementar fragmentos en tu actividad.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, le doy a una revisada a la info